# Why is it important to flush characters stored in buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, newline, flush

I wanted my python program to constantly update the download status without printing a newline and found out that I could use \r as follows.

```
print('Download status: '+str(download), end='\r')
```

Now I also read that I should also include flush = true

```
..., end='\r' flush=true)
```

But I can't exactly see the purpose of it. What problems could I face in the future if I don't use flush? I know that there is already a thread about it but I can't really wrap my head around how I could benefit my code since it is working normally even without flush.

Comment: BTW, that should be `flush=True`. And it's more efficient to let `print` do the conversion to string & concatenation: `print('Download status:', download, end='\r', flush=True)`

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, so does that mean if my terminal is displaying the download status updates even without flush=true, there is no need to use it then?

Comment: @PM2Ring Awesome. Please repost your comment as an answer. I will mark this as answered, so future newbies like me can easily understand the purpose of flush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, terminals are line buffered, so if the output from `print` doesn't contain a newline you won't see anything until a newline *is* emitted, or when the program ends and `stdout` is flushed as part of the closing process. In that situation you need to add the `flush=True` arg to the `print` call. You could also call `sys.stdout.flush()` explicitly, but it's more convenient (and slightly faster) to let `print` handle it. In Python 2, you have no option but to call `sys.stdout.flush()`.

However, in Python 3, the `print` function kindly performs a buffer flush for you if there's a `\r` (carriage return) in the output. So in that situation, you don't need to worry about flushing.

OTOH, be aware that some IDEs / terminals may not support this behaviour, and you will need to use either `flush=True` or `sys.stdout.flush()` with them. For that matter, some IDEs may not even behave correctly when printing with `\r` and `end=''` even if you do explicitly flush, for example [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3437).